# How to keep chemical formulas on the same line using chemmacros?

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, chemmacros, chemformula

I often refer to some chemicals often in my document (e.g. NH<sub>4</sub><sup>15</sup>NO<sub>3</sub>) and I keep getting line breaks in the middle of the chemical formula (e.g. if NH<sub>4</sub><sup>15</sup>NO<sub>3</sub> comes at the end of a line, sometimes NH<sub>4</sub> and <sup>15</sup>NO<sub>3</sub> are split onto different lines).

To get around this, and save typing, I created new commands for some chemicals:

```
\newcommand{\fan}{\mbox{\ch{^{15}NH4NO3}}} % \fan = 15NH4NO3 in mbox
\newcommand{\afn}{\mbox{\ch{NH4^{15}NO3}}} % \afn = NH415NO3 in mbox
\newcommand{\an}{\mbox{\ch{NH4NO3}}} % \an = NH4NO3 in mbox
\newcommand{\fnto}{\mbox{\ch{^{15}N2O}}} % \fnto = 15N2O in mbox
```

However, when I use my new commands, there's no space after the chemical formula in the text. If I put an extra space in the command, like this:

```
\newcommand{\afn}{\mbox{\ch{NH4^{15}NO3}} } % \afn = NH415NO3 in mbox
```

then, I get an extra unwanted space if a full stop comes after the formula in the text.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try loading `xspace` and add`\xspace` at the end of the macros. This is a difficulty with macros that have no argument. If it doesn't work, systematically add a pair of braces after each use of the macro in your document.

Comment: `\mbox` shouldn't be necessary in the first place…

Comment: @clemens For some reason, \mbox is necessary in my document, or else NH415NH3 gets split onto two lines if it comes at the end of a line. I'll ask a new question about this specific problem.

Comment: You must have an outdated version of `chemformula`, see my answer to your other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load xspace and add\xspace at the end of the macros. This is a difficulty with macros that have no argument. If it doesn't work, systematically add a pair of braces after each use of the macro in your document.

Thanks @Bernard!